# How to create a new package JSON file according to install a node package in a node module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have completed some react native code with `node_module`, but some installed packages in `node_module` are missing in the `package JSON` file.

I did try to install a new package and then removed some installed module in the `node_module folder`.

According to the `package JSON` file I have 588 package files in `node_module` after installation.
After updating the `package JSON` file I have only 143 packages in the `node_module` folder.

How can I create a new `package JSON` file with these parameters?

Comment: are you passing --save to npm install ?

Comment: You have written multiple sentences  into one and thats not readable.. Check your formatting... use "." full stops to stop a sentence and modify question accordingly.

Comment: Try to make use of the concept of sentences in the future. Highlighting keywords would be a nice bonus.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove package.json and start fresh using : `npm init`

So for all the missing packages in package.json you can run this:

```
 npm install --save <package>
```

Than you remove npm_modules folder from project and run npm install. it will re install all modules.And you should always include `node_modules` in `.gitignore` so that you don't end up commit them.

Comment: it's don't working I have also try "npm init" command with remove packagejson file but no create any new package json file to run npm init command .Can you give idea how much take time 'npm init' command bcs I have alredy check 8min .

Comment: @user1955030 you have node installed? after running npm init you have to fill 5-6 fileds after that package.json will be created.

Comment: @user1955030 try running npm -v. if it works you run npm init. and press enter enter enter until it lends back to terminal.

Comment: which type fields add ..
show command response 

'D:\test>npm init
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sensible defaults.

See `npm help json` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg>` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
package name: (test)'